# Click link where a class is child of

Tags: jquery

My code is this

```
<a onclick="......">
  <span class="addUserButton"></span>
</a>
```

I want to perform a click event on the link where the class `addUserButton` is child of that link.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/),  :has selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vrbr2/)**

```
$('a:has(.addUserButton)').click(function(){

});
```

Comment: in fiddle works fine, but when i plug it in i get `too much recursion` from firebug. Maybe I have too many a elements in my page?

Comment: Yes it could be because of lot of elements, you can parent element selector to narrow the control collection for selector, suppose the parent of these anchor tags has id parentId then $('#parentId a:has(.addUserButton)')

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".addUserButton").parent().click();
```

Comment: firebug says that there is 'too much recursion'